# Do local files survive an update? (LibGDX)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Do LibGDX local file types survive updates on Android? I'm aware that preferences do survive updates and that only external files survive an uninstall.
I want to be sure user save games will survive app updates and I can't find an answer to this either on the wiki or in the javadocs.

Comment: What do you mean by local files?

Comment: In libgdx there are internal files (read only), local files (read & write), and external files (read & write but volatile) as defined here - https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, local files are stored in the application's internal storage that is private to the app. And yes, they will **stay unmodified** even after the app is updated.

FYI, In Android, the `SharedPreferences` and database are also stored inside the app's private internal storage. So the behavior of local files will be same to these, i.e., they do survive updates but not uninstall or "clear data".